# How does foam rolling affect workouts?

Tags: foam-rolling

I am interested in the science behind foam rolling (If there is any). I would like to know if there is any evidence backed studies showing that it is effective, or is it still considered pseudo science?

Comment: Effective at what? You can try for yourself to show that self-massage can improve movement quality and work out some kinds of soreness. What's the claim to prove or disprove?

Comment: That foam rolling has any positive benefits,be it before or after workout or without workout at all?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6465761/

This is  comprehensive study done on foam rolling. It basically shows that it has some increase in flexibility and a decrease in soreness, without jeopardizing muscle performance. It shows this is especially true in the short term but it's hard to determine for the long term.

On a personal note, I use it pretty much only when I have a particularly sore area, as I do feel it release some tension. I can't say for sure if it helps because I use it in combination with other things like stretching, massage etc.

I think more research needs to be done possibly, but it seems to be slightly helpful in the short term. Possibly in the long term too if you include injury avoidance

Comment: Not science, but I can definitely back the 'tension relief' in the second paragraph. I use it exclusively after running, and it does miracles on every single leg muscle.